# G*Power ANOVA repeated measures within-between interaction

Tags: mixed-model, repeated-measures, statistical-power, effect-size, gpower

I'd love to get a sanity check on a sample size calculation I'm running in G*Power. I'm planning a study with 2 groups and 2 measurement points, aiming for a f of 0.10 because, to my understanding, it's equivalent to a Cohen's D of 0.20. The correlation between the outcome at baseline and at follow-up is 0.75, so I entered that as the "corr among rep measures". I'm going for power of 0.8 with alpha=0.05.

When I input that information into GPower as shown below, I get a much lower required sample size estimate than if I ignore the within-subjects component and treat it as just a between-subjects study. I knew repeated measures improves power, but I didn't think it would be this much. Does the GPower screenshot below seem correct given what I explained?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The power of a repeated measures anova is highly dependent on the correlations between the measures. 0.7 is a pretty high correlation, so we expect a large increase in power.